# What is the PHP Code for Woo Customer Type (New/Returning)

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

I've seen that there is a Customer Type column in the in-built Analytics.
Can someone tell me the php code for this? I want to use it somewhere else and it seems like a ready function which I could call upon.

Thanks!

[image: WooCommerce Orders Analytics]

Comment: At first glance here's the code: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/8.2.1/plugins/woocommerce/src/Admin/API/Reports/Orders/Stats/DataStore.php#L663

Comment: but I've no idea when that's available or how to use it etc. You might do better asking at https://developer.woocommerce.com.

Answer (score 0):

A custom function would be required. You can check for any orders placed by customer details, but I'd recommend using either customer id (best option as you can get the logged in user's id very easily) or customer email address..

```
function wpse419519_is_returning_customer( $customer ) {
    
    $args = array(
        'limit' => -1, //Returns all the orders
    );
    
    if ( is_email($customer) ) { //If you want to check with email address
        $args['customer'] = $customer;
    } else {
        $args['customer_id'] = $customer;
    }
    
    $orders = wc_get_orders( $args );
    
    if ( !empty($orders) ) {
        return true;
    }
    
    return false;
}
```

You can now call `wpse419519_is_returning_customer()` anywhere after the user is authenticated to check if it is a returning customer. For example:

```
$is_returning = wpse419519_is_returning_customer(get_current_user_id());

if ($is_returning) {
    //Returning customer
} else {
    //New customer
}
```